# how to sum by two groups in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

i want to get the sum by the groups in crystal reports..

```
    amount     order      id
  ----------------------------- 
    100.00       1       A001
    100.00       1       A002
    200.00       1       A001
    100.00       2       A001
    100.00       2       A002
    400.00       2       A002
```

and i want them to group like this

```
    amount     order      id
  ----------------------------- 
    300.00       1        A001
    100.00       2        A001
    100.00       1        A002
    500.00       2        A002
```

what i've done so far is in formula fields i make `SUM({amount},{id})` and name it byID and 2nd formula is `SUM({@byID},{order})` and name it byOrder which is it gives me an error saying "This field cannot be summarized.". uhmm..how to do this ? glad for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Approach is wrong.. trying to sum which is already summarized.

first group by `id` and then group by `order` and take summary for both groups.

Comment: what i want sir is how to do this in crystal report "Select amount from tbl Where order = @variable and id = @variable" ? something like that..

Comment: do you need a query to use in crystal report?... actually above method will give you the same result in crystal design